# Can I use the PWM pins as regular digital input/output pins?

Tags: arduino-uno, pins, pwm, input

In regards to the arduino which has pwm pins, can I use these pins as normal input/output digital pins or not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: Not directly related to the question but perhaps noteworthy, you can also use the Analog-In pins as regular digital IO.

Comment: Yes that is true and an often overlooked fact. Indeed most pins have multiple functions. Arduino pinout diagrams are extremely useful to see what an individual pin is capable of. Most have more than one function. Some have more than two functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use them as ordinary digital io pins. PWM is essentially a normal digital output pin that is repeatedly turned on and off at a high rate.

The magic is that the turning off and on is done in the hardware according to the duty cycle  (I.e. there is no need for software to perform the on/off operations) . This is why only some pins can do h/w PWM, because the PWM hardware is not added on to all pins.

If you are not using the pin for PWM, it is available for you to use as required.